# Topics in ZeroMQ REP sockets

Tags: sockets, filtering, zeromq, publish-subscribe

When using ØMQ socket of type `SUB`, one may use

```
sub_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'topic')
```

Is the same possible also with `REP` sockets, allowing a worker to only handle specific topics, leaving other topics to different workers?

I'm very afraid that it is impossible, quoting http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html:

> In the current versions of ØMQ, filtering happens at the subscriber side, not the publisher side.

But still, I'm asking if there is some trick to achieve that, because such a functionality would have a huge impact on my infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Can I assume that you've got a `REQ` or `DEALER` server socket that sends work to `REP` workers, that then respond with the completed work back to the server?  And that you're looking for a way to make your server communicate to specific clients rather than just pass out tasks in a round-robin fashion?

Can't do it.  [See here](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket), those sockets are only, always, round-robin.  If you want to communicate to a specific client, you must either have a socket that talks only to that client, or you must start the communication from the client (switch your socket pairing so the worker requests whatever work its ready for, and the server responds with it, and then the worker creates a new request with the completed work).  Doing anything else gets much more complicated.

Comment: You are absolutely right in your assumptions, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Ok, thanks for your clear answer, seems like I'll have to instantiate separate ''DEALER'' for each topic :(

Comment: Is there a reason that the communication has to start from the server?  Doing req/router and just initiating from the worker would likely vastly simplify your architecture, there are several examples in the [ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all).

Comment: I hope I didn't use improper terminology -- I'm using exactly this topology: https://github.com/imatix/zguide/raw/master/images/fig17.png.

The communication starts from the clients, but unfortunately, I have several topics, each of which needs a lot of RAM and hence requires a subset of dedicated workers (or services if following the terminology of the figure) on different machines. If I could use subscription to topics by the services, things would be nice and simple. But because you say this is impossible, I'll have to instantiate separate ``ROUTER``-``DEALER`` broker for each topic.

Comment: I understand a little better now, but you still have other options.  I would change it to `CLIENT/REQ -> BROKER/ROUTER | BROKER/ROUTER <- WORKER/REQ` - have the worker initiate a request to tell the BROKER that it's ready for work, and what type of work it will accept.  The broker waits on that, and then when it receives a request from a client, it looks for open requests from workers, and sends the work to an available worker (or sits on it until a worker indicates it is ready).  Then the worker makes a new request with work done (which essentially opens it for more work).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for sharing this idea! I was stuck thinking in terms of native zmq devices and it didn't come to my mind I could create a broker myself... As well as initiate the requests by workers. Furthermore, this would allow me to even implement a more sophisticated topic management, such as regex matching which is not supported natively. My only concern is about the performance. Native zmq devices use almost no CPU as I see it, while my own broker could easily become a bottleneck. Nevertheless, I don't see any crucial obstacles for making the broker multi-threaded if necessary.

Comment: The broker is essentially your server, it's that piece in the middle of your linked topology... but the important thing to remember is that ZMQ isn't a complete messaging system out of the box, it's really more a set of tools that you can use to build your messaging system.  There's nothing inherently wrong or not performant about having a broker as part of that system, if it helps you achieve your messaging goals.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again, after few days of programming, I have working implementation where workers initiate requests for work, telling the broker what kind of work they can handle -- exactly as you suggested. I also wrote my own implementation of request broker, which allows more complex topics subscription mechanism than just prefix matching.